# How can we get the text field value during onSubmit method in latest react-hooks-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

How can we get the text field value during `onChange` method in latest react-hooks-form in version `7.31.2`. Now I am getting blank values during on click on Submit button.Could someone please advise me on this.

Here is my CSB link for reference:
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-currying-5gng14?file=/src/App.js

```
const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm();
const [formRegister, setRegister] = useState({ _id: "", name: "", email: "" });

const onChange = (e) => {
  e.persist();
  setRegister({ ...formRegister, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};

const onSubmit = (e) => {
  const formData = new FormData();

  for (let key in formRegister) {
    formData.append(key, formRegister[key]);
  }

  if (picture) formData.append("photo", picture);

  const config = {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  };
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.put(
        "http://localhost:8000/service/joinrequest",
        formData,
        config
      );

      if (res.data.success) {
        setIsSent(true);
      } else {
        console.log(res.data.message);
        setHelperText(res.data.message);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setHelperText(e.response.data.message);
    }
  };
  fetchData();
};
```

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} encType="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input
    id="name"
    name="name"
    type="text"
    {...register("name", {
      onChange: (e) => {
        // how can we get the value here
      },
      required: true,
      maxLength: 30,
    })}
  />
  <label>Email</label>
  <input
    id="email"
    name="email"
    type="email"
    {...register("email", {
      onChange: (e) => {
        // how can we get the value here ?
      },
      required: true,
      pattern: {
        value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
        message: "Please enter a valid email !",
      },
    })}
  />
</form>;
```

Comment: You have `onChange={onChange}` but that's the wrong event it should be `onInput={onChange}`. This will fire your onChange handler and update `formRegister`. But `formRegister` state is just extra baggage you do not need. Since you are using `react-hook-form` just take the data passed in to `onSubmit()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the registered `onChange(e)`, e is a synthetic event which contains a property `nativeEvent` which has a `path` property pointing to the native element.

```js
{...register("name", {
  onChange: (e) => {
    const val = e.nativeEvent.path[0].value;

    // you can update formRegister here, 
    // but note it updates on every character
    setRegister(previous => ({
      ...previous, 
      name: val
    }))
```

---

**On clicking the Submit button**

The data from the form is passed into the `onSubmit()` callback

```js
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    console.log(e.name);  // whatever was typed into the name field

    for (let key in e) {
      formData.append(key, e[key]);
    }
```

Comment: May i know where do we pass the ``const val `` in the above answer suggested..

Comment: I saw in your code ***// how can we get the value here ?*** - is that not what you were after? It definitely gives you the value typed into the input. Did you want something else?

Comment: BTW I was going to add - the `onChange()` doesn't fire on clicking the Submit button, only when you change the value in the `name` field. (And on every keypress).

Comment: Sorry when I set a break point, I am not able to see the text typed in the name filed available in the formregister

Comment: So, you aren't interested in getting the value inside the `onChange()` event?

Comment: I would like to get the values on on submit button alone, someone suggested me to try to  onChange because in react-hook form V7 and above there is a changes in getting the value.

Comment: Because of the way React hooks work, I don't think you can use a breakpoint. React needs to re-render in order for the hooks data to appear in state.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `watch` from react-hook-form API to get the changes in the text of input field. Can you elaborate your goal why you wanna do it. This may help understand if we can use `watch` or not and if overriding `onChange` is the only solution to achieve it?

Comment: For me its not necessary to get values using ``watch``, if possible handleSubmit is fine.